# Neuron specialization in the Visual System

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

Can someone point me to a good resource to explain how neurons in the visual system become sensitive to visual features?  I understand that specific neurons fire for things like direction of motion, orientation, etc.  How does this specialization get “programmed in” during development?  I’m sure that training from experience is key but how does a specific neuron become specialized for a feature and its neighbor becomes specialized for another feature?

I’m a noob and curious how different neurons specialize to fire for simple features in the LGN but more complex features in higher visual areas.  Just go straight to Huble & Wiesel?